# WITH your own or IN your own

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is it better to say:

> I hope you enjoyed this content, and find it beneficial and
>   inspirational **with** your own analysis.

Or

> I hope you enjoyed this content, and find it beneficial and
>   inspirational **in** your own analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is entirely smooth, I would change it just a little to

> I hope you enjoyed this content, and find it beneficial and useful for your own analyses.

This has the implication that what you have just given them could be used in their own work (in an audience's case, you generally use the plural, hence "analyses" not "analysis").

Comment: Just a heads up that the question has been edited, so you may want to take that into account in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I hope you enjoyed this content, and find it beneficial and
>   inspirational with you own analysis.

I hope you enjoy this content and find it beneficial and inspirational.

> Or: I hope you enjoyed this content, and find it beneficial and
>   inspirational in you own analysis.

I hope you enjoyed this content, and find it beneficial and inspirational in* you**r** own analysis.

I personally feel that your have no need to say "in your own analysis" as it is 'understood'. By 'finding' or 'enjoying', you have made an opinion. Also, the phrase just sounds wrong.  (**In** your opinion, **By** your analysis... but the sentence would need a rewrite for those to be usable.)